# How can I set up a keyboard shortcut for switching input source?

Tags: macos, keyboard, menu-bar, text-input, input-source

I have to change my language option very often. It is hard when I write something with combination of both "*English*" & "*Bangla*", because I have to change that option rapidly.

Is there any way to set a keyboard shortcut, so that I can change my language option by it while typing?

I am using MacBook Pro with OS X.

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Screen Shot of my Preference:

[image]

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Go to **System Preferences** → **Keyboard** → **Shortcuts** → **Input Sources** and define a keyboard shortcut there. As you only have two sources, set a single shortcut for one of the options, then pressing the shortcut will toggle the input sources.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. :)
But unfortunate thing is there is no **"Input Sources"** option in my "Keyboard" section, in preference. :( Watching your interface it seems like you are not using OSX 10, isn't it? Can you have any solution for OSX 10?

I am attaching the screen shot of "Preference" to my main question. Please take have a look.

Comment: @Tulon In Mountain Lion, the default keyboard shortcut for switching input sources is predefined as ⌥⌘Space. Going from memory, I believe the way to change it on 10.8 is in System Preferences → Language & Text → Input Sources → Input source shortcuts.

Comment: Yes, i got it. After going to:
`Preferences → Language & Text → Input Sources → Input source shortcuts`
I see that the remain 2 options there:
01. "Select previous input source ⌘Space" &
02. "Select next input source in menu ⌥⌘Space"

are disabled. Because these two shortcut was used for **"Searching Spot light"**. After change this shortcut now it's working. Thanks a lot @George Garside. Have a nice day. Take my hug. :)

Comment: ... for who didn't figure out already, it's possible keep just one of the shortcut bindings and cycle through the different choices (e.g. if one has 3 or more input sources), selecting the desired one: **just hold `control` (`^`)** and press `space` repeatedly for cycling to the next keyboard layout.

Answer (score 13):

grgarside's answer was great.

Here is an another solution for multilingual user.
If you want to switch among three or more input methods quickly or switching to a specific input method by shortcut directly, you may try [IMEShortcuts](https://web.archive.org/web/20180726061345/http://www.rockcell.net/) (disclaimer: I'm the IMEShortcuts creator)

It allows you map a shortcut to a input method. You can switch to a specific method immediately by you-defined shortcut without using cmd+space to rotate input methods. It works well on OSX 10.9 ~ 10.12.

[image]

Please have a try, I'm glad to hear your feedback. Thanks

Comment: The original site went down, the link has been replaced to the most recent usuable version archive.org has available. The description only mentions macOS 10.10-10.12 though, so the utility may or may not work with more recent versions.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, making sure to be on a certain language no matter what the state currently is. I often don't know which language I'm on. So telling which language is faster than toggling.

Comment: This is a great tool! Can we somehow get it up and running? Maybe using github pages?

Answer (score 4):

Follow the bellow steps for `macOS Ventura`:

1. Go to your system settings.
   [image]
2. First add the input resource.
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
3. Now add the newly added input source with custom keyboard shortcuts.
   [image]
   [image]
4. Done. Now type your keyboard shortcuts and see if the input sources are toggling properly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and unconfused answer. This answer should be marked as "Answered" since it works on latest MacOS versions.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Apple's Bangla keyboard, you can type English by holding down the Option/alt key.  If you are using Bangla Qwerty, you can do this by pressing the Caps Lock key.

Answer (score 2):

Example configuration for Karabiner

```json
{
  "title": "select_input_source example",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "Change input source by ctrl + 1/2/3 en/es/zh",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "1",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "control"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "select_input_source": {
                "input_source_id": "^com\\.apple\\.keylayout\\.ABC$"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "2",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "control"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "select_input_source": {
                "input_source_id": "^com\\.apple\\.keylayout\\.Latin*"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "3",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "control"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "select_input_source": {
                "language": "zh*"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

based on https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#example_select_input_source

Answer (score -3):

Open System Preference and click language and text instead of keyboard. You can find input source there.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions