# Switching to Russian keyboard from Japanese still types in English

Tags: mac, software-update, high-sierra

I feel like this (bug?) started happening after one of the latest OS updates applied.

I'm currently using Mac OS X High Sierra (10.13.2).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start OS
2. Switch language to Russian
3. Able to type in Russian
4. Switch language to English

Result:

Still types in English, even though it shows Russian as selected language....

Comment: Did you say this right?  Don't you mean that it still types Russian after switching to English, or more likely still types English after switching to Russian?

Comment: How do you switch the language?

Comment: @TomGewecke Yes, it still types in English after switching to Russian.

Comment: @patrix I used to switch by pressing Ctrl+Space

Comment: Do you have Chinese, Japanese, or Korean keyboards active?

Comment: @TomGewecke I have the Japanese keyboard active and it works fine.

Comment: There is a known bug with 10.13.2:  Switching from Japanese (or Chinese or Korean) to Cyrillic, Arabic, Hebrew, or Greek will not work, you must first switch to US (or some other Latin layout) in between.  Are you perhaps typing "English" using the Japanese IM?

Comment: @TomGewecke Thanks for the hint. Yes, I used to type in English using the Japanese Language's Romaji input method. Now when I disabled that "Romaji" and use the "US Keyboard" for "English", switching to Russian is working fine now. If you post answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known bug with 10.13.2: Switching from Japanese (or Chinese or Korean) to Cyrillic, Arabic, Hebrew, or Greek will not work, you must first switch to US (or some other Latin layout) in between.

Ask Apple to fix this via their [feedback page](http://www.apple.com/feedback).

Answer (score -1):

Language isn't the same as input method. You need to [change your input method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/135373/15606) to achieve what you want.

Comment: I have been using this for years. It's just not working anymore as it used to be.