# How can I make an app keyboard shortcut override the global default?

Tags: keyboard, macos, shortcut

For instance, <kbd>Ctrl-Space</kbd> is a commonly accepted "code completion" shortcut in several IDEs (IntelliJ IDEA etc.), however on the system level it is "change input source (language)" shortcut. I don't need other languages while in IDEA, so can I have <kbd>Ctrl-Space</kbd> trigger code completion in IDEA without changing the global default?

PS: I know about [How can I set up a keyboard shortcut for switching input source?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135370/how-can-i-set-up-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-switching-input-source) but the solution there is to change the global default (which I don't want to do).

Answer (score 1):

I always used JetBrains products, and always using the 'ctrl space' for code completation. Never had such issue ....

In any case, just go to System preferences > Keyboard -> Shortcuts and disable that specific shortcut .

In my case, I have no such 'ctrl space' for anything listed ...

Comment: `ctrl-space`is defined but disabled by default, it is a standard shortcut for "switch input source" (language). You probably didn't need several languages on your computer, I have 3 :) I can of course change it to something else (unfortunately not to Command-Tab for compatibility with Windows), but ideally I'd keep both defaults but have them depend on the context.

Comment: @davka : I use actually use six different languages and two jetbrains products at same time. Not all are properly programming languages, but, all of it  has its own sintax ... ( php, html, css, javascript, sql and golang ) ( phpstorm and goland )

Comment: So how do you change the language (input source)? Have you defined a custom shortcut?

Comment: Ow. You were talking about languages likw english, or portuguese ... In this case, I don't ! Actually I speak portuguese but my keyboard and OSx is english. By the way. My external keyboard doesn't works the 'e' key. To round this, I ve made a knew keyboard mapping, which actually is the same than another language input source. ( Well, here in brazil an apple keyboard it is pretty expensive ). Now, i have to press 'option + w' to get the 'e' . Takes a bit to get used, but works. To achieve that I used a keyboard map editor app named Ukelele  .

Comment: Once you have my new map on the proper folder ( I dont remember exactly where.. check Ukelele docs ). Go to system preferences -> keyboard -> input source . Click on the plus button to add any new map on the list. In your case that you use many, check the option 'show input in menu bar'  .

Comment: thanks. Being able to edit/create new keyboard layout would be useful too, however this is not what I'm looking here.